# how to write case statement in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Here I want the date difference in current date and input date.In following I write case statement but it returns NULL for `curdate()` .whats going wrong with this?

```
SELECT admit_patient_details.admit_pat_doctor,admit_patient_details.admit_pat_dept,admit_patient_details.admit_pat_name,
                admit_patient_details.admit_pat_room_no,admit_patient_details.admit_pat_bed_no
                ,patient.patient_name,patient.in_date,patient.discharge_date,
                CASE patient.discharge_date
                    WHEN '0000-00-00' THEN DATEDIFF(curdate(),patient.in_date)
                    ELSE DATEDIFF(patient.discharge_date,patient.in_date)
                END AS totaldays FROM admit_patient_details,patient 
                having admit_patient_details.admit_pat_name=patient.patient_name
```

some column output:

```
admit_pat_name |  in_date   |   discharge_date |     totaldays   |
Satish Mokashi |2015-05-19  |  2015-05-22      |     3           |
guddi jagtap   |2015-05-12  |  2015-05-20      |     8           |
Rahul Patil    |2015-04-17  |  NULL            |     NULL        |
```

Comment: Can you show some sample data or create a sqlfiddle? I suspect it might be due to `datatypes`. Check the datatype of your `discharge_date` column.

Comment: @Beginner: Please see my newly edited question I don't have that much reputations to insert image of database. I checked datatypes both are dates, then why this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column is defaulted to `NULL` not `0000-00-00`. So you can give this a try:

```
SELECT 
  admit_patient_details.admit_pat_doctor,
  admit_patient_details.admit_pat_dept,
  admit_patient_details.admit_pat_name,          
  admit_patient_details.admit_pat_room_no,
  admit_patient_details.admit_pat_bed_no,
  patient.patient_name,
  patient.in_date,
  patient.discharge_date,
  CASE
    WHEN patient.discharge_date IS NULL THEN DATEDIFF(curdate(),patient.in_date)
    ELSE DATEDIFF(patient.discharge_date,patient.in_date)
  END AS totaldays 
FROM admit_patient_details,patient 
HAVING admit_patient_details.admit_pat_name=patient.patient_name
```

Comment: Yes my patient.discharge_date column haves default value as NULL but I tried your solution also but it returns same output as previous....

Comment: It returns me NULL as I had changed my query as you suggest.I actually want when patient.discharge_date=NULL then datediff=curdate()-patient.in_date i.e.datediff='2015-05-23' - '2015-05-20' = 3

Comment: in your solution WHEN statement doesn't reach. I write it as like this and it works:CASE 
    WHEN ISNULL(patient.discharge_date) THEN DATEDIFF(curdate(),patient.in_date)
      ELSE DATEDIFF(patient.discharge_date,patient.in_date)
     END AS totaldays